# error en SQL syntax al invocar funcion con php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Esta funcion debe actualizar la contraseña de mi usuario en la base de datos pero me aparece un error en pantalla al hacerla:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

---

```
function resetUser($conexion, $id){    
    mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuario SET clave = 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', primer_login = '0' WHERE id = ".$id."") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

problema de comillas

```
mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuario SET clave = 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', primer_login = '0' WHERE id = '.$id.'") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
```

sigo aprendiendo

Comment: Si las columnas `primer_login` y `id` son numéricas, no tienes que usar las comillas. En ese caso, la consulta se puede escribir así: **`"UPDATE usuario SET clave = 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', primer_login = 0 WHERE id = $id"`** O sea, cualquier valor numérico va sin comillas simples en la instrucción SQL. Ten en cuenta que tu consulta es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Un usuario mal intencionado puede manipular el contenido de `$id` y hacer estragos en tu sistema sin que te enteres, dado que pasas ese valor directamente a ejecución. Es un grave error hacer eso.

Comment: como puedo evitarlo? cambiando la consulta propiamente @A.Cedano?